# Unable to start debugging on the web server. Only for ASP NET Debbuger

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am using vs2012 .net 4.5

Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly.

I have been trying to solve this issue for weeks and I cannot find the solution

This I have tried:

1. Checking which configuration on project properties was causing the problem: I found out that this happens when I set ASP .NET Debugger for debugging.
2. Reinstalled .NET framework
3. Enabled on IIS all authentication type: Anonymous, Forms, Windows Authentication and ASP NET personification

This happened since I changed my application to run under IIS. I was using VS Development Web server..

Could you please gimme some advice on that?

Thanks

Comment: @dumbledad instead of just writing your own comment for a duplicate, actually flag it through the interface so others can vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 on Windows 8.1. For me the fix was to add Windows Authentication to IIS using 'Turn Windows features on or off'

[image: Turn Windows features on or off screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in a WebApi in VS2013, follow the next steps to fix the problem:

1. Right click on the Web project.
2. Select "Web" tab.
3. Click button "Create virtual directory".

In this case a WebApi requires a virtual directory configured on IIS to work correctly and be able to debug.